# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

please i want develop my login page but i am bignner 
the problem in the check.php "this file check the login"
when i enter my information in the login it redirect my to check.php
and i see

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in C:\AppServ\www\check.php on line 31
```

this is code 31

```
$use=new mysql;
use->sql();

?>
```

exactly

```
use->sql();
```

please what is the problem 
note : i use php version 5

Comment: You're missing a `$` before `use`. That's required any time you use the variable, not just when you're declaring/initializing it.

Comment: thanks bro workked